# Бот C# на VkNet. Почему ловит не все события?

Tags: c#, vknet

Почему у меня ловит не все события? Пробую писать сообщения в беседу с этой группой, но в консоль выводится не все.

```
while (true) // Бесконечный цикл, получение обновлений
        {
            var s = vkApi.Groups.GetLongPollServer(190776459);
            var poll = vkApi.Groups.GetBotsLongPollHistory(
               new BotsLongPollHistoryParams()
               { Server = s.Server, Ts = s.Ts, Key = s.Key, Wait = 25 });
            if (poll.Updates == null) continue; // Проверка на новые события

            foreach (var a in poll.Updates)
            {
                if (a.Type == GroupUpdateType.MessageNew)
                {
                    Console.Write(a.MessageNew.Message.Text);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

хоть кода и больше, но попробуйте использовать это:

```
while (true)
        {
            var longPoll = _api.Groups.GetLongPollServer(_groupid);
            _url = string.Format("{0}?act=a_check&key={1}&ts={2}&wait=25",
                longPoll.Server,
                longPoll.Key,
                json != string.Empty ? JObject.Parse(json)["ts"].ToString() : longPoll.Ts
                );
            json = webclient.DownloadString(_url);
            var msgcol = JObject.Parse(json)["updates"].ToList();
            foreach (var item in msgcol)
            {
                if (item["type"].ToString() == "message_new")
                {
                    string message = item["object"]["body"].ToString();
                    long? userid = Convert.ToInt64(item["object"]["user_id"].ToString());
                    SendMsg(userid, message);
                }
            }
        }
```

предварительно добавив поля класса:

```
private static WebClient webclient = new WebClient() { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
private string json = string.Empty;
private string _url = string.Empty;
```